# Java Stream map(...) - error while passing custom Function, though accepting methodReference

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

For code readability I am creating Custom Function Interface, while passing it as mapper in `map(...)`, a compilation error is coming. Need help. The below example simplified for the problem.
e.g.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Try<K,T> {
    public K apply(T t);
}


public class Concrete{
    //example
    public static String checkFunc(Integer integer) {
        return "Vivek";
    }
}

public class CustomTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
        
        Try<String,Integer> try1 = Concrete::checkFunc;
        
        integers.parallelStream().map(try1); // compile error
        //The method map(Function<? super Integer,? extends R>) in the type Stream<Integer> is not 
         //applicable for the arguments (Try<String,Integer>)

        integers.parallelStream().map(Concrete::checkFunc); // this is perfectly fine

    }
     
}
```

I am trying to pass mapper something like above. How to do that correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must pass in something that implements `java.util.function.Function`.  You have two main choices:

- make `Try` extend `Function`
- convert `Try` to a `Function`, e.g. `map(try1::apply)`

You cannot get around the need to pass in a `Function` to `map`.